# Objective-C: Calling non-immediate base class implementation from within derived class

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, I have a base class A, with instance method -(void) doSomething. Class B is derived from A and overwrites doSomething. Class C is derived from B. In the implementation of C's doSomething, I want to invoke A's doSomething (instead of B's). How do I achieve this? I know I can use [super doSomething] to invoke the immediate super-class implementation, but what if I need a more basic implementation higher above in the inheritance tree, like in the case mentioned above. In C++ you would simply do the following:

```
void C::doSomething()  
{  
    A::doSomething();  
}
```

How do I achieve the same thing in Objective-C?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's no good way to do this in Objective-C. Can you give more details on the purposes of the methods? There may be a better way to get this done than trying to call the super-super class.

Comment: I have written a base class that loads descriptions for input fields from an XML file (NSDictionary) and populates a UITableView with UITableViewCell objects containing UITextFields. The base class provides a default validator isFieldValid that checks against a regex that can be stored in the XML file. In some cases I want additional checks (at run-time), so I can overwrite the isFieldValid, call the super class implementation to have it perform the static regex check and additional run-time checks. Now, if I derive a second time, how do I call the original check in a DRY way?

Comment: Why not just configure the additional checks in the plist file and do everything in a single method? And what does the class hierarchy represent?

Comment: The XML file contains section declarations for the table view (header, rows, footer). Each row contains key, label, placeholder, and optional regex. With the regex you can do static pattern checks. In my particular case I have a page with personal information, including birth date. On this page I want to enforce that the person is at least 18 years old. I have another page that looks identical, but this time the age check is not required. So I derived the second page's view controller from the first one. The first is derived from a base class that handles field management including regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the code into a static method which takes an instance as an argument. Example:

```
@interface A : NSObject
{
}

+(void)joe_impl:(A*)inst;

-(void)joe;

@end

@implementation A
+(void)joe_impl:(A*)inst{
    NSLog(@"joe: A");
}

-(void)joe{
    [A joe_impl:self];
}
@end
@interface B : A
{
}

-(void)joe;

@end

@implementation B

-(void)joe{
    [super joe];
    NSLog(@"joe:B");
}
@end
@interface C : B
{
}

-(void)joe;

@end

@implementation C

-(void)joe{
    [A joe_impl:self];
    NSLog(@"joe:C");
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will do it this way. I thought there might be a "cleaner" way in terms of object-oriented programming. You would never do this in C++, i.e. write a static member function that expects a this pointer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Objective-C, and the desire to jump around the class hierarchy that way is symptomatic of a serious design flaw.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this limitation, so I won't waste any more time searching for a way to mimic the C++ style. Actually, this is not a design flaw, but facilitates DRY design. At least true for C++ and virtual functions. You will see such design practice in many OO frameworks, for example MFC.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [super doSomething] for calling superclass methods